# Выбор между блоком и элементом в BEM

Tags: html, css, бэм

Допустим есть такая структура[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серый - родительскиий блок.
Внутри него два похожих элемента с элементами внутри.

Как лучше обозначить красный элемент - элементом или все же блоком?

С одной стороны он встречается несколько(2) раз, с другой - только в сером блоке. Кроме того при обозначении как блок мы получаем более логичную структуру но вместе с этим теряем логическую привязку к серому блоку.

Как правиильно обозначать в этом случае?

Answer (score 3):

Сущность может быть одновременно блоком и элементом. Называется [Микс](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81)

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}

.catalog{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:15px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.card{
  width:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 15px 15px;
  padding:10px 10px 50px;
  background-color:red;
}
.card__header{
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
  margin:0 0 10px;
}
.card__body{
  display:flex;
}
.card__item{
  min-height:50px;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background-color:green;
}
.card__item:first-child{
  width:30%;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
}

.catalog__card{
  margin:0;
  width:calc(50% - 5px);
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">

  <div class="card catalog__card">
    <div class="card__header"></div>
    <div class="card__body">
      <div class="card__item"></div>
      <div class="card__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card catalog__card">
    <div class="card__header"></div>
    <div class="card__body">
      <div class="card__item"></div>
      <div class="card__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: card catalog__card -> Здорово!
я старался избегать таких миксов, но может в этом и есть смысл